# How to store string which contains ; to String[] in java

Tags: java

I have input string in

```
String x = "&#x0AB8;&#x0ACD;&#x0AA5;&#x0ABF;&#x0AA4;&#x0ABF;";  
// WHich is Hex NCR cooded string contains & # x 0 and ; for e.g. &#x0AB ;

String sFinalData = 87508~~~~20~false@87512~x~~~22~true
```

I am using following code.

```
String[] sPropertyString = sFinalData.split("@");
for(int iter=0;iter<sPropertyString.length;iter++){
   String[] sProperty = sPropertyString[iter].split("~");
   sPropertyName = sProperty[1];
   System.out.println("O/P..."+sPropertyName );
}
```

But for above code it is showing array index out of bound.

I need to store this Hex NCR string to database.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This editor automatically covert HEX NCR to word so please consider hexNCR code String x.

Answer (score 0):

`sPropertyName = sProperty[1];`is array index out of bound Exception come from this line? why you use index 1 , maybe `sProperty.length`is 1.then the max index is 0.

Comment: Because I want to store HEXNCR code which I will get from sProperty array from position 1.

Comment: which line throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException？

Comment: sPropertyName = sProperty[1]; Throws array index out of bound

Comment: I have already said that maybe sProperty.lengthis 1.then the max index is 0.